# Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present in Spring MVC Java

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, file-upload

**Controller:**

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/media", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
@ResponseBody
public MediaDto addMedia(@RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    LOG.info("Adding media file with name={}", file.getOriginalFilename());
```

**Configuration**

```java
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(90000000);
    commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}
```

**Angular**

```
<input onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)" id="chooseFile" name="file" type="file"
```

Answer (score 0):

The id in the input tag should be named the same as the @RequestParam(name = "file")name parameter in the controller

Comment: This didnt work.

Comment: Hello, I tried the demo you provided. I am using Postman and it is normal to try to call the interface.
You can also try it with Postman to see if the problem is with the front end or the back end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).